# Obtener ID al insertar en tabla sql con nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, postgresql, express

necesito que cuando hago un insert en la tabla de users me devuelva en una respuesta el id y el createdat. Cuando ejecuto mi codigo id viene undefined claramente, no se como podria extraerlo, la base es postgresql por si acaso:

```js
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, phone, email } = req.body;
  const date = new Date();

  const response = await pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO users(name, phone, email, createdat) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)",
    [name, phone, email, date]
  );
  console.log(response);
  res.json({
    message: "Usuario creado satisfactoriamente",
      user: { id, date },
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la cláusula [`RETURNING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-insert.html) de *PostgreSQL*.

La sintaxis de `RETURNING` es similar a la de un `SELECT`, pero se va a aplicar a los registros que inserte el `INSERT`.

> The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually inserted.

Tu *query* sería

```
"INSERT INTO users(name, phone, email, createdat) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING id"
```

... suponiendo que `id` es el nombre de la columna que quieres obtener.

Aplicándolo a tu *endpoint*,

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, phone, email } = req.body;
  const date = new Date();

  const response = await pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO users(name, phone, email, createdat) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING id",
    [name, phone, email, date]
  );

  // Accedemos la primera row insertada
  const { id } = response.rows[0];

  res.json({
    message: "Usuario creado satisfactoriamente",
    user: { id, date },
  });
});
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: muchisimas gracias! no conocia esa clausula, me sirvio!